# Part does not exist in table construction, but I don't explicitly index that high

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I am simply at a loss. I've tried every way I can think of to fill a matrix of values with a function I wrote. I've attached a couple of screenshots.

Here is the error:

[image: evaluated cell and output of a few relevant subexpressions]

The function evaluates on the defined interval `{1,m}` where `m=2` in this simple case.

[image: function evaluated does not produce errors]

I've tried doing this directly with `Table[]`:

[image: code with <code>Table[]</code>]

What am I doing wrong? I've tried this with nested `For[]` loops, and same issue. It's behaving like `m=3`, generates a `Part[]` error, and exits.

Here's the notebook:

```
EnumerateBHBasis[d_, n_, m_] := Sort[Join @@ Permutations /@ 
IntegerPartitions[n, {m}, Range[0, d - 1]]]; 
\[DoubleStruckB][i_, ψ_] := Module[{scaling, \[DoubleStruckB]ψ}, \[DoubleStruckB]ψ = ψ; If[Length[\[DoubleStruckB]ψ] < i, Return[Null], scaling = Sqrt[ψ[[i]]]; \[DoubleStruckB]ψ[[i]]--; Return[{scaling, \[DoubleStruckB]ψ}]; ]; ]; 
\[DoubleStruckB]†[i_, ψ_] := Module[{scaling, \[DoubleStruckB]†ψ}, \[DoubleStruckB]†ψ = ψ; If[Length[\[DoubleStruckB]†ψ] < i, Return[Null], scaling = Sqrt[ψ[[i]] + 1]; \[DoubleStruckB]†ψ[[i]]++; Return[{scaling, \[DoubleStruckB]†ψ}]; ]; ]; 
\[DoubleStruckN][i_, ψ_] := Module[{scaling, \[DoubleStruckN]ψ}, \[DoubleStruckN]ψ = ψ; If[Length[\[DoubleStruckN]ψ] < i, Return[Null], scaling = ψ[[i]]; Return[{scaling, \[DoubleStruckN]ψ}]; ]; ]; 
InnerProduct[α_, β_] := Module[{}, If[α == β, Return[1], Return[0]]; ]; 
\[DoubleStruckCapitalH][n_, m_, α_, β_] := Module[{\[DoubleStruckCapitalH]β, α\[DoubleStruckCapitalH]β, tunneling, intersite, intrasite, chemical}, 
tunneling = 0; For[i = 1, i <= m - 1, i++, For[j = i + 1, j <= m, j++, \[DoubleStruckB]jβ = \[DoubleStruckB][j, β]; \[DoubleStruckB]†i\[DoubleStruckB]jβ = \[DoubleStruckB]†[i, \[DoubleStruckB]jβ[[2]]]; \[DoubleStruckB]†i\[DoubleStruckB]jβ *= \[DoubleStruckB]jβ[[1]]; \[DoubleStruckB]†jβ = \[DoubleStruckB]†[j, β]; 
     \[DoubleStruckB]i\[DoubleStruckB]†jβ = \[DoubleStruckB][i, \[DoubleStruckB]†jβ[[2]]]; \[DoubleStruckB]i\[DoubleStruckB]†jβ[[1]] *= \[DoubleStruckB]†jβ[[1]]; If[0 < \[DoubleStruckB]†i\[DoubleStruckB]jβ[[1]] && α == \[DoubleStruckB]†i\[DoubleStruckB]jβ[[2]], tunneling += (-J)*\[DoubleStruckB]†i\[DoubleStruckB]jβ[[1]]; ]; 
     If[0 < \[DoubleStruckB]i\[DoubleStruckB]†jβ[[1]] && α == \[DoubleStruckB]i\[DoubleStruckB]†jβ[[2]], tunneling += (-J)*\[DoubleStruckB]i\[DoubleStruckB]†jβ[[1]]; ]; ]; ]; intersite = 0; 
 For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, \[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI] = \[DoubleStruckN][i, β - 1]; \[DoubleStruckN]\[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI] = \[DoubleStruckN][i, \[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI][[2]]]; \[DoubleStruckN]\[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI][[1]] *= \[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI][[1]]; If[0 < \[DoubleStruckN]\[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI][[1]] && α == \[DoubleStruckN]\[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI][[2]], 
    intersite += (U/2)*\[DoubleStruckN]\[DoubleStruckN]β\[DoubleStruckCapitalI][[1]]; ]; ]; intrasite = 0; For[i = 1, i <= m - 1, i++, 
  For[j = i + 1, j <= m, j++, \[DoubleStruckN]jβ = \[DoubleStruckN][j, β]; \[DoubleStruckN]i\[DoubleStruckN]jβ = \[DoubleStruckN][i, \[DoubleStruckN]jβ[[2]]]; \[DoubleStruckN]i\[DoubleStruckN]jβ[[1]] *= \[DoubleStruckN]jβ[[1]]; If[0 < \[DoubleStruckN]i\[DoubleStruckN]jβ[[1]] && α == \[DoubleStruckN]i\[DoubleStruckN]jβ[[2]], 
      intrasite += V*\[DoubleStruckN]i\[DoubleStruckN]jβ[[1]]; ]; ]; ]; chemical = 0; For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, \[DoubleStruckN]iβ = \[DoubleStruckN][i, β]; If[0 < \[DoubleStruckN]iβ[[1]] && α == \[DoubleStruckN]iβ[[2]], chemical += (-μ)*\[DoubleStruckN]iβ[[1]]; ]; ]; 
 Return[tunneling + intersite + intrasite + chemical]; ]; 
Clear[d, n, m, Ψ, i, j]; 
d = 2; 
n = 1; 
m = 2; 
Ψ = EnumerateBHBasis[d, n, m]; 
ℋ = Table[\[DoubleStruckCapitalH][n, m, Ψ[[i]], Ψ[[j]]], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, m}]; 
ℋ = Table[0, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, m}]; 
Do[α = Ψ[[i]]; β = Ψ[[j]]; ℋ[[i,j]] = \[DoubleStruckCapitalH][n, m, α, β], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
ℋ
n
m
α
β
\[DoubleStruckCapitalH][n, m, Ψ[[1]], Ψ[[1]]]
\[DoubleStruckCapitalH][n, m, Ψ[[1]], Ψ[[2]]]
\[DoubleStruckCapitalH][n, m, Ψ[[2]], Ψ[[1]]]
\[DoubleStruckCapitalH][n, m, Ψ[[2]], Ψ[[2]]]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of (or in addition to) images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What is $\Psi$?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was looking for a way to upload the notebook, but couldn't find an easy way to do it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher $\Psi$ is a 2-element list of basis vectors $\{0,1\},\{1,0\}$

Comment: I use Copy (after selecting cells) and Paste. As the linked Q&A discusses, sometimes you need to do something else.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 I've added the notebook that I used to generate the errors.

Comment: Better replace the `For` loops by `Do`s. The iterators in `For` get not scoped, so they might mess up quite a lot.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The `Do`s were originally nested `For`s. I only used `Do`s to determine if I had somehow coded the `For` loops incorrectly. The `For`s produced the same error.

Comment: Still, one has to start somewhere. `For` is an easy way to produce buggy code.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Oh ... I misunderstood you. Thought you meant the `Do` loop to produce the matrix, but you meant those `For`s in the modules.

Ha! Making that replacement fixes the code. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

`For` loops produce globally scoped iterators. Replacing all `For` loops in my `Module` (see code in original question) definitions with `Do` loops clears all errors.

Review the comments for more detail.

Comment: What does `Module` have to do with it?  The iterators would be global outside the modules, too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nothing. I was referring to my specific implementation where I iterate over `Module` functions which themselves call nested `For`-loops. Because I iterate over `i,j` in both the functions and the loops, I end up indexing some iterators higher than intended. Edited my answer to reflect this miscommunication.